# Contact form 7 - How to send mail to two different E-mail Address

Tags: plugins, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using Contact form 7 plugin for my WordPress website. When User submit the form E-mail is sent to Admin with subject and all the details like name, email, phone, city, zip-code etc..At the same time I also want to send another E-mail to another Admin with fewer details like different subject line and name, email and phone. How to achieve this ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question (how to send separate email with different info): see the mail2 tab below the first mail entry on the Mail tab. Click the checkbox to get another Mail form where you can set up the second email.

Answer (score 0):

[image: How I receive message on multiple emails using contact form 7.]
 please see screenshot. go to Contact form > open your desire form > Click on Mail tab enter emails use comma "," to make them separated